# AutoHotKey - Creating state dependent hotkeys

Tags: state, autohotkey, hotkeys

Is it possible to create state dependent hotkeys with AutoHotKey? I know it is possible to create certain hotkeys in a dependent state when working with [#IfWinActive](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) but how about creating hotkeys inside a hotkey itself?

**Example**

```
F1::
    Gui, Show, center center h500 w500, Just a window
    return

    F2::
        MsgBox, 0, F2, You have pressed F2 inside the F1 hotkey
    return
return
```

The problem here is that **F2** is not state dependent and will trigger as soon as you press it.

**Possible solution**

```
F1::
    state := true

    Gui, Show, center center h500 w500, Just a window
    return

    #If (state = true)
    {
        F2::
            MsgBox, 0, F2, You have pressed F2 inside the F1 hotkey
        return
    }

    GUIclose:
        Gui, destroy
        state := false
    return
return
```

This is a possible solution and works very well. However, is there an easier solution to it than doing it this way?

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, there is no better way. I'd say you pretty much nailed it and the code looks rather clean. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite "easier", but imo better looking and my preferred way:

```
F1::
    Hotkey, F2, F2_action, ON
    Gui, Show, center center h500 w500, Just a window
return

F2_action: ; this is a label not a hotkey
    MsgBox, 0, F2, You have pressed F2 inside the F1 hotkey
return

GUIclose:
    Gui, destroy
    Hotkey, F2, F2_action, OFF
return
```

I made use of the [hotkey](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm)-command here, which is specifically made for

> but how about creating hotkeys inside a hotkey itself

Answer (score 1):

I would go the route of adding 2 conditions to an `#If`

```
F1::
    state := true
    Gui, Show, center center h500 w500, Just a window
Return

#If state and WinActive("Just a window")
    F2::MsgBox, 0, F2, You have pressed F2 inside the F1 hotkey
#If
```

Not sure if this is what you already ruled out when stating you tried `#IfWinActive`

Comment: I'm not really working with #IfWinActive in this case, it was just an example I used for reference. But I appreciate your idea :)